# C# Print specific excel worksheets

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Currently I got this code that prints all worksheets in a workbook:

```
MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;

MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(generatedFile);

foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in MyBook.Worksheets)
{
    Excel.PageSetup ps = (Excel.PageSetup)ws.PageSetup;
    ws.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    ws.PageSetup.Order = Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver;
    //ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    //ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 50;
    //ws.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
}
MyBook.Worksheets.PrintOutEx();

MyBook.Close(SaveChanges: true);
MyApp.Quit();
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyApp);
```

My question is how can I print only selected worksheets (ones where a specific cell is not empty) all on the same print job?

If I'm not mistake calling `WorkSheet.PrintOut()` for n WorkSheets would create n print jobs, right?

Comment: Add if statement on your loop to check this cell if not empty then continue else go next sheet.

Comment: Yes, but how can I then print those ones all in one print job?

Comment: what about create new workbook and add the correct sheet to it then print it as one print job.

Comment: I was getting an error then I tired that. I'll give it another shot.